# Change the options passed to formik (Field) form after selecting the value from other dropdown

Tags: formik

Below is the code which I am using. When I am changing the data for Division the state of district list is changed but it is not shown in the form. I need to click on the form and the changed state data is reflected. I want it to get reflected once the state is changed.

```
function Input(props) {
    const { label, name, ...rest } = props
    return (
        <div>
            {/* <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label> */}
            <Field id={name} name={name} {...rest} />
            <ErrorMessage name={name} component={TextError}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function Select(props) {
    const { label, name, options, ...rest } = props
    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            {/* <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label> */}
            <Field as='select' id={name} name={name} {...rest} >
                {
                    options.map(option => {
                        return(
                            <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                                {option.key}
                            </option>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </Field>
            <ErrorMessage name={name} component={TextError}/>
        </div>
    )
}

function Test() {
    const [divisions, setDivisions] = useState([])
    const [districts, setDistricts] =useState([])
    const [blocks, setBlocks] = useState([])
    const [initialValues,setInitialValues] = useState({
        divisionCode:"",
        districtCode:"",
        blockCode : "",
        name       : "",
    })
    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        divisionCode    :Yup.string().required('Required!!'),
        districtCode    :Yup.string().required('Required!!'),
        blockCode       : Yup.string().required('Required!!'),
        name            : Yup.string().required('Required!!'),
    })
    async function getDivisionList() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get("APIURL")
            return (res.data.response)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
    function getDistrictList(divisionCode) {
            axios.get("APIURL")
                 .then(res=>{
                    setDistricts(res.data.response)
                    return res.data.response[0].value
                 })
    }
    function getBlockList(districtCode) {
        axios.get("APIURL")
             .then(res => {
                 setBlocks(res.data.response)
             })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
            getDivisionList().then(res => { 
                        setDivisions(res) 
                    });
    }, [])
    const onSubmit = values => {
        console.log('Form data ',values)
        console.log('Saved data ',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(values)))
    }
    return (
        <Formik
                initialValues       = {initialValues}
                validationSchema    = {validationSchema}
                onSubmit            = {onSubmit}
        >
                {
                    formik =>   <Form>
                                    <Select control='select' label='Division' onBlur={e => {  var data = getDistrictList(e.currentTarget.value)}} name='divisionCode' options={divisions} />
                                    <Select control='select' label='District' onBlur={e => {  getBlockList(e.currentTarget.value)}} name='districtCode' options={districts} />
                                    <Select control='select' label='Block' name='blockCode' options={blocks} />
                                    <Input control='input' type='text' label='Name' name='name' />
                                    <button type="submit" disabled={!formik.isValid}>Submit</button>
                                </Form>
                }
        </Formik>
    )
}

export default Test
```

Thanks in Advance. It will be very helpful.

Comment: I think you should use two options enable reinitialise and innerRef of formik for the form to show changes

Comment: can you please explain with example

Comment: <Formik  enableReinitialize={true}> add this to formik component. Let's see if it makes any difference.